# The browser caches HTML pages in a grunt / angular application. How does one invalidate it when building?

Tags: html, angularjs, gruntjs, browser-cache, yeoman

I have a webapp built with angular/grunt/yeoman.

This is the problem that I have:

File **home.html:**

```
<h1>hello</h1>
```

I `grunt build`, then check the page in my brower. Everything is fine.

Then I change
**home.html** to

```
<h1>hello 2</h1>
```

I `grunt build`, then in my browser I still see `hello` if I navigate to this page by clicking links. If I refresh the page with the browser button, I see `hello 2`.

Why is that ? How to tell grunt to build the app so the browser re-fetches every html page ?

Note: I have no problem with html/css since they are concatenated into a single file, and the file name changes every build.

I am using chrome.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Any solution? I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Use a plugin to clear the browser cache, for example: [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn)
- Use a web server that explicitly forbids caching

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I would like a way to refresh it without having to click the refresh button. (without any special action from the end user)

Comment: Use a web server that forbids caching. I'm a node.js developer so I use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-server). with the  `-c-1` flag.

Comment: In fact, the request doesn't hit the web server when I look at the logs. The request hits the server only when I use the refresh button...

Comment: @pinouchon Yes. This behaviour is called caching ;-)

Comment: Actually chrome doesn't make GET requests it should make. If I try in firefox, I do not have this problem.

Comment: The content is cached. Therefore the browser want load it again. You need to clear the cache and then make sure that it won't be cached again.